# compareTo returns -1 even though strings match Java

Tags: java, string, search, binary-search-tree, compareto

I can't figure this out why, I have a binary tree made up of object Nodes, I can't really post all the code but it reads appointments from a file and inserts them based on their last name, currently i have about 5 appointments, i am trying to add search functionality based on last name.

it finds the correct Node, but instead of returning 0, returns -1

My search method

```
private boolean contains(String x, BinaryTreeNode  t){
        if (t == null)
            return false;

        int compareResult =  x.compareTo(t.info.getLastName());
        System.out.println("Printing t.info " + t.info.getLastName() + "\n Compare Result: " + compareResult + "\n Printing X: " + x);

        if(compareResult < 0){
        //  System.out.println("\n Less Than \n");
            return contains(x,t.left);   // Its in the left subtree
        }   
        else if (compareResult > 0){
        //  System.out.println("\n Greater Than \n");
            return contains( x, t.right);  // Its in the right subtree
        }   
        else {
            System.out.println("\n" + t.info + "\n");
            return true; // Found Match
        }   
    }
```

My output

```
Printing Tree

Bob, Saget,     Zafar,      1/3/4,      3/5/6
Kamer, Silo,        Dkido,      3/5/6,      3/5/7
Kevin, Wu,      Sine,       4/5/6,      3/5/6
Mano, Billi,        Zafar,      4/5/6,      3/4/5
**************************************
*    XYZ Hospital Appointment Maker  *

*   1. Add Appointment               *
*   2. Search by Last Name           *
*   3. Print Tree                    *
*   4. Exit                          *

2


 Enter Last Name: Kevin

Printing t.info Bob 
 Compare Result: 9
 Printing X: Kevin
Printing t.info Kamer 
 Compare Result: 4
 Printing X: Kevin
Printing t.info Kevin 
 Compare Result: -1
 Printing X: Kevin
```

Comment: Try with trim,    int compareResult =  x.compareTo(t.info.getLastName().trim());

Comment: Not really just learnt from experience, let me move it to answer now. If it helped then accept the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the strings look similar but there maybe trailing spaces. So use `trim()` with `compareTo()` method. Change this

```
   int compareResult =  x.compareTo(t.info.getLastName());
```

to

```
  int compareResult =  x.compareTo(t.info.getLastName().trim());
```

You may like to trim `x` also before calling `compareTo`